# Adding/removing tabs to UITabBarController programatically gives console warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In my application, I have a custom UITabBarController that is set as the rootViewController.  During the life span of the application, I programmatically add/remove additional tabs based on user interaction, and when doing so I see the following message various times in the console:

```
Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.
```

Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?

*EDIT*

Here's a simplified example of how I'm adding the additional tabs (example just has 1, but there's actually 4 being added).

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
viewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Title";
UINavigationController *navViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[self setViewControllers:@[ navViewController ] animated:NO];
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to edit the items in your tab bar?

Comment: Done.  It's a simplified example, but should still have the same effect.

Comment: How are you animating the addition and subtraction of items in your custom tab bar? It sounds like you are getting this warning at those times.

Comment: The code above is exactly what I'm doing.  The tabs are getting added programmatically after the UITabBarController's viewDidLoad, but I'm not sure why it's giving those warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `MyCustomViewController` implementing one of the deprecated two-phase rotation methods?

```
– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
- didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
- willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

As the error message says, these have been deprecated (since iOS 5.0). Have a look at their documentation to see what the replacement mechanism is (basically, use 
`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead).

Comment: Nope, and I just tried this using vanilla UIViewController + UINavigationController and it still gives the warning twice... =\